# How to set the value for an HTML element from external javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using an external javascript file (eg:`myjs.js`) with function `setval()` to set the `innerText` property of a HTML lable.

I have PHP page with `<lable id="abc"></lable>` and I have included `myjs.js` in `<head>` section. `myjs.js` is included in `<head>` section of one more PHP file and I'm calling `setval()` from this file, so when it runs it must set the `innerText` of lable in the first PHP file.

Is it possible to achieve? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. 
I hope I made question clear.

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing a a "PHP page", it's all HTML on the client. Forget about what PHP is doing, think about the client end on the browser. Pretend it's just an HTML page and you'll find the answer.

Comment: @F.Calderan Hm, maybe you should not have fixed `lable`, it might cause problems if the OP really uses that.

Comment: @bažmegakapa if the problem is only caused by a mistyping the whole discussion has no real problem to be answered :) @user725719 could you confirm if you're using `<label>` ?

Comment: As this has nothing to do with either PHP or ajax, I've removed those tags.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, move your include of `myjs.js` to the *bottom* of the page (just before or after the closing `</body>` tag). Then it's just:

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerText = /* ...the text */;
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/itokes) | [source](http://jsbin.com/itokes/edit)

If you can't move the include for some reason, you can put the above code in a function, e.g.:

```
function updateTheLabel() {
    document.getElementById("abc").innerText = /* ...the text */;
}
```

...and then put this script just after the label:

```
<label id="abc"></label>
<script>
updateTheLabel();
</script>
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/itokes/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/itokes/2/edit)

If you don't want to do that (and it's a bit ugly, mixing script tags into your markup like that), you could wait for some kind of event that occurs when the page is ready. Search for "javascript dom ready event" and you'll see a **lot** of discussion of this, and lots of solutions. If you're using a library [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries), odds are high (but not 100%) that the library will have something for you. You probably don't want to wait for the `window` `load` event, because that fires **very** late in the page load process (after all external resources — images and such — are loaded).

(Can't do a live example of the above without knowing what library, if any, you're using; but again, there are dozens of "dom ready" solutions out there.)

Or I suppose worst case, you could poll, using this in `myjs.js`:

```
function updateTheLabel() {
    var elm = document.getElementById("abc");
    if (elm) {
        elm.innerText = /* ...the text */;
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(updateTheLabel, 50);
    }
}
setTimeout(updateTheLabel, 0);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/itokes/3) | [source](http://jsbin.com/itokes/3/edit)